# Installing VTK with pip

Tags: python, pip, vtk

I'm using Python 3.7 on Arch Linux.
I've been trying to install Mayavi with pip but it always fails when installing vtk. So I found out that even when trying to install vtk by itself via pip [(which should work)](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/) that vtk is really not installing. I get this error:

```
$ sudo pip3 install vtk
Collecting vtk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for vtk
```

This seems like a very dumb error on my part, but I really can't understand what's going on. VTK should be [compatible with Py3 now](https://blog.kitware.com/vtk-7-0-0/) as far as I know. `pip` was installed with `get-pip.py` and everything else has always worked perfectly.

Curiously enough, `pip2 install vtk mayavi` works.

Any ideas?

PS.: I'm avoiding creating a separate environment for work-related issues.

**EDIT**

I did the manual approach:

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/13/7f/735fbc0dd78c91ad3693cfdfe5c91603899fc8e24909f935d46d2fde6559/vtk-8.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
$ sudo pip3 install vtk-8.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
vtk-8.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Which I don't know what's causing. I've tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053131/failure-installing-vtk-from-pypi-on-x86-64) but I can't make the first `pep` command work.

Answer (score 2):

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: )

Among the [currently released files](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/8.1.1/#files) there are no binaries for Python 2.7 and there is source code. Either you should try a different version of Python (2.7, 3.4-3.6) or compile/install [VTK from sources](https://www.vtk.org/download/).

> vtk-8.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

You're trying to install a Python 2.7 binary wheel for Python 3.7. That's impossible.

Comment: Oops, hadn't realized that it was a cp27 file. I check PyPI and indeed there is no cp37 wheel yet.

Comment: At the moment, VTK 8.1.1 is not prepared for Python 3.7. So even installing from sources is not going to work. I tried it. See [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17363).

Answer (score 0):

The wheel has not been published on pip yet, you can download and install  one from vtk.org directly : https://vtk.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

You can manually compile the VTK version packages you want and put them in the dist-Packages directory.I have a specific method.