# Cannot import mayavi: "ImportError: cannot import name implements"

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I'm trying to use Mayavi in Python 2.7, but cannot import it. My OS is Ubuntu (LTS). Here is the code:

```
import numpy
from mayavi.mlab import *
```

The following error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/script/my_script_name.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/mlab.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/camera.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .engine_manager import get_engine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/engine_manager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mayavi.preferences.api import preference_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/preferences/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .preference_manager import preference_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/preferences/preference_manager.py", line 30, in <module>
    from apptools.preferences.api import (ScopedPreferences, IPreferences,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apptools/preferences/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from preferences import Preferences
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apptools/preferences/preferences.py", line 9, in <module>
    from traits.api import Property, Str, Undefined, implements

ImportError: cannot import name implements
```

I have tried force-reinstalling the packages mayavi, implements, traits, but to no avail. I tried both with pip and with apt.

**Edit:** I think the error is that mayavi cannot access VTK for my Python 2.7 installation. When I try to pip force-reinstall mayavi, I get the error "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement vtk (from mayavi)". That error is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880687/installing-vtk-with-pip). I do not know what to do, since both vtk and vtkpython are properly installed (with apt) and working - the issue is with mayavi and pip not knowing what to do?

Comment: did u have VTK and A GUI toolkit, either PyQt4, PySide, PySide2, PyQt5 or wxPython.

Comment: I have VTK and PyQt4, and later tried to install PySide and wxPython. Maybe the problem is that maya is using wxPython instead of PyQt? wxPyhon is known to have issues with Enthought libraries (like traitsui, which the error is related to). How do I tell maya to use PyQt4 instead of wxPython? From mayavi documentation: "Currently, Mayavi itself should work with the new wxPython 4.x. However, traitsui, pyface, and other ETS packages do not yet support it so the UI will not work correctly. Older versions should work. PyQt/PySide should work largely out of the box. PySide2 is still young so YMMV"